# proxy rewrite location header field on redirect

Tags: openshift

Is it possible to configure the proxy on a secured route so that on a redirect the location header field in the response is rewritten to HTTPS?

I get `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://complan-complan.a3c1.starter-us-west-1.openshiftapps.com/planner`

when I log in to the application. But also without login the request to the above URL is redirected to HTTP and again to HTTPS.

Thanks!

Comment: What language/framework/server are you using? You need to configure your app to read X-Forwarded-* headers.

Comment: It is a Wildfly server and I already asked this question to the Undertow people: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46521373/redirect-to-relative-url-after-login
Unfortunately it seems like I cannot change the behavior of the internal redirection mechanism especially that after login.

Comment: Have you tried this https://mirocupak.com/configuring-wildfly-behind-a-reverse-proxy-with-tls/ ?

Comment: Yeah man, that does it! No redirect to HTTP no more. Is it this setting (`proxy-address-forwarding=true`) which causes Undertow to consider the incoming protocol as secure though it is still HTTP?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the exposed route in OpenShift is set to TLS edge termination then the build-in HAProxy will terminate the HTTPS connection and create a new HTTP connection to your application.

To get the original client-ip/protocol/port the proxy inserts the HTTP headers `X-Forwarded-For`, `X-Forwarded-Proto` and `X-Forwarded-Port`.

For redirection to work correctly you have to tell your framework/server to use those fields. In your case with Wildfly you can follow [theses instructions](https://mirocupak.com/configuring-wildfly-behind-a-reverse-proxy-with-tls/)

There are samples for other frameworks/servers in the OpenShift FAQ:
https://developers.openshift.com/faq/troubleshooting.html#_how_do_i_redirect_traffic_to_https